# Using Solr to index a latin1 column that contains utf8 data

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, solr

I'm working on a PHP-based webapp that has an existing MySQL database where all text columns use latin1 encoding, but they have utf8 data in them.

This works fine for the PHP app, which uses latin1 encoding for the db connection to retrieve the data then outputs directly to the browser, telling the browser the page is utf8.

However, we are now trying to use Solr to index the database, using the MySQL JDBC connector, and we are getting gibberish words in the index.

Here is the connection string:

```
<dataSource
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/db_name?characterEncoding=latin1&amp;characterSetResults=utf8"
    user="user" password="password" />
```

Is there a way to get Solr to retrieve the data as latin1, and then treat it as utf8 without converting it?  I've tried changing the characterEncoding and characterSetResults parameters in the JDBC connection string, to no avail.

I'm sure the right way to fix this is to convert all the text columns to utf8, but I'd prefer not to go that route (yet) because it will break the webapp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct, the right way is to fix your database. Trust me, I've just gone through this (to fix a solr installation, oddly enough) and the sooner you can fix it the less pain it will cause you.

There's two ways to fix your data stored in the wrong encoding:

1. `mysqldump` all the data as latin1 (`--default-character-set=latin1`), edit the table definitions to be `CHARACTER SET=utf8` instead of `latin` and then reimport the dump.
2. Run two alter statements for each mis-encoded column

   `ALTER table MODIFY columns BINARY`

   `ALTER TABLE MODIFY column VARCHAR(255) CHARSET utf8`

   by modifying to BINARY first, you can trick MySQL in to not running the latin1=>utf8 conversion which, in your case, would double-encode and break your data.

If your db is large, 1 is going to be faster than 2.

Immediately after that, just configure your PHP application to communicate with MySQL using utf8. This can be done by sending `SET NAMES utf8` as the first query of every connection. If PHP is already sending utf8 data to MySQL, that should be all you need to do.

If, after this fantastically worded and detailed answer you're still looking for a hack... Try and configure JDBC to connect as UTF8 but see if there's a way to get it to send a pre-command before it does any work.

If you make that command: `SET NAMES latin1` then, theoretically, Solr should connect as UTF8 and process data coming from the connection as UTF8, but MySQL will consider the connection a latin1 connection and not convert any data coming from your latin1 columns.